# How do I access Private APIs in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I need to get the value of `mac address` and `username` and `computer`. I want to do this with `networkingPrivate`. But I can’t able to access it.

I wrote in the `manifest.json` file this:

```
"permissions": ["networkingPrivate"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can't because they're private exactly for the purpose of being private, not public API. It's also [whitelisted to specific extensions by Google or its trusted associates](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/api/_permission_features.json?l=492&rcl=ebcf8f6f72e0a219fcaf110db22334b16eb7f6bf).

For your own personal use you may have success by running Chrome with a custom command line parameter `--whitelisted-extension-id=abcd` where abcd stands for the 32-character id of your extension as seen on chrome://extensions page when developer mode switch is enabled in the top right corner of the page. Or you can mimic a trusted extension's id by finding its manifest.json and copying its `"key"` to your own manifest.json.

For a public extension you'll have to use a workaround. For example, write a separate utility and invoke it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API.